# PHP calls to custom fields not being made. Query seems to be blocking them

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

```
<ul class="footer_banner_box_container clearfix">
    <div id="text-4" class="widget widget_text">
        <h3 class="box_header">Our Doctors</h3>
        <div class="textwidget">
            <h3 id="our-docs" style="margin: 10px 20px; padding: 20px; color: #002664;">Our team includes an array of trained experts, who can make critical decisions regarding care that typically would require multiple office visits.</h3>
            <br />
            <ul class="bxslider">
                    <?php
                $args = array('post_type' => 'Doctors', 'orderby' => 'rand');
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="view">
                            <li><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(160,225) ); ?></li>
                            <div class="mask">
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif;  ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
<ul class="footer_banner_box_container clearfix">
    <div id="medicenter_contact_details-4" class="widget contact_details_widget">
        <h2 class="box_header"><?php the_field('hospital_name'); ?></h2>
        <ul class="footer_contact_info_container clearfix">
            <li class="footer_contact_info_row">
                <div class="footer_contact_info_left"><?php the_field('hospital_address_line_1'); ?></div>
                <div class="footer_contact_info_right"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="footer_contact_info_row">
                <div class="footer_contact_info_left"><?php the_field('hospital_address_line_2'); ?></div>
                <div class="footer_contact_info_right"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="footer_contact_info_row">
                <div class="footer_contact_info_left"><?php the_field('hospital_phone_number'); ?></div>
                <div class="footer_contact_info_right"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_content_1" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <p style="color: #002664;"><?php the_field('footer_content_1'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_content_2" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <?php the_field('footer_content_2'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

In my footer template, I'm trying to recreate preexisting widgets. I have a WP_Query setup to call a custom post type, and then I'm passing the post_thumbnails to a jQuery carousel.  Below that I have another widget area that I'm trying to make more dynamic by using Advanced Custom Fields to fill the values.  However, when I have my footer template structured this way (as it has to be), the php calls to get the custom field values do not get made. When I have the second footer_banner_box_container above the first one it works but as it sits it does not. Could be the theme but I'm really coming up empty. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify what you expect and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the second `footer_banner_box_container` is trying to fetch those fields from the last post in the custom post type query directly above it, because that was the last value given to the [global `$post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) when `$query->the_post()` was called in that loop.

I assume you want the fields from the *main query* and not that secondary query, so you must add [`wp_reset_postdata();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after the loop of any additional queries, to restore `$post` to its original value. That way, any template tags that internally use the value of the current `$post` will use the correct data and give expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_reset_postdata();` after the loop so the custom field data is again fetched from the original post data.

[Have a look at the codex for more details.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)